# Cauchy sequence of sine function

Tags: cauchy-sequences

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence of nonnegative numbers. Prove that 
$$\{\sin (x_n + 5)^{1/3}\}$$ is a Cauchy sequence by checking the definition of Cauchy sequence.

I tried $$|x_m-x_n| < \epsilon$$
$$|\sin(x_m+5)^{1/3} - \sin(x_n+5)^{1/3}|$$ and apply sum to product. Please help for the following steps!!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ba+b^2),$$
and thus
$$a-b=\frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ba+b^2}.$$

Set $a=\sin(x_m+5)^{1/3}$ and $b=\sin(x_n+5)^{1/3}$ and use the fact that 
$$\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2\cos\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right).$$

Comment: and letting |xm-xn|<arcsin(3epsilon/2) ?